# Разделение на светлых и темных

Tags: javascript, color

есть страница, на этой странице расположены элементы... цвет фона страницы может меняться в любой... элементы расположенные на странице имеют начальный цвет `#000(черный)`, а если установить такой же цвет для фона, то их просто не будет видно... тоже самое если установить любые темные цвета, элементы будут плохо отображаться... собственно интересуют как мне разделить цвета на светлые и темные? чтобы я мог в зависимости от этого менять цвета элементов..

```
if(фон == светлый) элементы=темные;
if(фон == темный) элементы=светлые;
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сравнивать цвета на контрасность. Можно [переводить цвета в HSV](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)#RGB_.E2.86.92_HSV) (можно даже не считать H) и сравнивать их по яркости, причем если яркость отличается незначительно, сравнивать еще и насыщенность.

В вашем случае возьмите два цвета для элементов. Для каждого цвета фона смотрите который из этих цветов контраснее, тот и задавайте.

Comment: если `L` из `HSL цвета фона` будет > `50%`, я задаю для элементов черный цвет, иначе - белый. так?

Comment: Да, например так. Если между черным и белым выбирать, то это самый простой вариант

Answer (score 0):

Одна из возможных формул:
`if (red*0.299 + green*0.587 + blue*0.114) > 186 use #000000 else use #ffffff`
Пару альтернативных вариантов можно найти [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/872294)

Comment: Возможно стоит заменить формулу на `red * 0.2126 + green * 0.7152 + blue * 0.0722` (https://habrahabr.ru/post/304210/)